# Saving Gmail mail items to PDF results in html type files

Tags: gmail, pdf, google-drive, printing

I want to save an actual email from Gmail as a off to Drive, directly from my mobile phone (lg g2). For example I may save a receipt from play store as a PDF.

However the resultant file turns out to be a rambling html type file. I use the print option from Gmail.

Saving an attachment works fines.

I can't locate any options or settings that may impact the printing process.

I would appreciate any advice from others who may have experienced this issue.

Thanks

Comment: All e-mails are in html format.
What about downloading an HTMLtoPDF converter?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid double handling the files as I am away from my desk when I want this functionality. I would probable wait until I am next in the office and do a batch of the.

Comment: if you want there are thousands of HTMLtoPDF on the play store